# How to check what is running on local Port 3000 with Node?

Tags: node.js

When I use `npm start` to view my app with local Port 3000, I am getting an error saying `Port 3000 is already in use`.

I checked to see if I had any windows opened using that app, but I don't. Is there a way to check to see what is running on that Port and how do I go about closing it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try this - `netstat -an |find /i "listening"`

Comment: run this command in terminal : `lsof -i:3000`

Comment: you can use `npx kill-port 3000` to kill the port